# How to use require in ionic 2

Tags: ionic-framework, requirejs, ionic2

I want to use require.js in ionic 2.
I uses something like

```
var createLogger = require('redux-logger');
var persistState = require('redux-localstorage');
```

However, the browser complaint about "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined". I could not think of a way to include requirejs to my ionic 2 project. Please help.

Comment: should you use module (import and export) in ES5/6 ? =))

Comment: @nahoang9698 'redux-logger' and 'redux-localstorage' are both js file. I could not import them directly. Just wondering how would I deal with js library in my ionic app.

Comment: reference https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/4986 . It can help.

Answer (score 8):

I am also trying to integrate RequireJs with Ionic 2.
For your problem try this

> declare var require: any;

use it after all your imports and before @Component or @Service

Comment: where do we put it?